# Read more button not working while adding HTML into paragraph in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement read more button with HTML content. When I am adding simple text then it is working fine. I want add HTML inside `class="show-read-more"`with read more button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Add Read More Link</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxLength = 100;
$(".show-read-more").each(function(){
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
        var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
        var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
        $(this).empty().html(newStr);
        $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
        $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
     }
     });
     $(".read-more").click(function(){
     $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
     $(this).remove();
   });
 });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.show-read-more .more-text{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="show-read-more"><h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2><p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industries standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You have paragraph inside paragraph which is wrong also have header inside `show-read-more` which is not allowed. I have restructured your html code and it is working now. please check below code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxLength = 100;
$(".show-read-more").each(function(){
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
        var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
        var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
        $(this).empty().html(newStr);
        $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
        $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
     }
  });
  $(document).on("click",".read-more", function(){
     $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
     $(this).remove();
   });
 });
```

```css
.show-read-more .more-text{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2><p class="show-read-more"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industries standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: @AkashSolanki, please see my updated post, run the code snippet to see it working

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example based on your provided code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Add Read More Link</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="show-read-more">
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
        <p>
            <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industries
            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
            recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var maxLength = 100;
            $(".show-read-more").each(function () {
                var myStr = $(this).text();
                if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
                    var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
                    var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
                    $(this).empty().html(newStr);
                    $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
                    $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
                }
            });
            $(".read-more").click(function () {
                $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-read-more .more-text {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

everything is working as you wanted, the only thing which you were doing wrong was that you weren't ordering the code correctly, if you have further doubts then please let me know..

Comment: it is not working still showing simple not exact I want. h1 tag is not working.

Comment: what h1 tag you are talking about ?

Comment: Sorry h2 tag and strong tag. It not showing like qoura shows images strong word.